# How to move from file to file in a loop, MatLab?

Tags: matlab, directory, filenames, file-rename

Is there a way to simply load the name of the first file in a directory without specifying its name, and then in each iteration move on to the next file in the directory?

I have the problem of the file names being named with 1, 1.5, 2,2.5,3, 3.5 endings etc... so num2str(X) in an iteration will not help to locate the file.

I am trying to rename them using strrep(s1,s2,s3), but yet again I run into the same problem of loading them into a loop!

I understand that I should have named them with more planning at first, but these files are much too large to run the simulations again.

This is what I have to rename the files:

```
%%%RENAMING A FILE%%%

%Search directory to get number of files
 d1=dir('\MATLAB\Data\NumberedQwQoRuns');
 numfiles = length(d1)-2;


for a=1:numfiles
%Search subdirectory if necessary for count of those folders
d2=dir('\MATLAB\Data\NumberedQwQoRuns\Run'num2str(a));
subdir = length(d2)-2;
for b= 1:subdir

origname= PROBLEM???

Newname=['Zdata' num2str(b) '.txt']
Newfile= strrep(origname, origname, newname)
movefile(origname,Newfile)

end
end
```

Thank You Very Much for your help,
Abid A

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my solution:

```
%# get runs subdirectories
BASE_DIR = '/path/to/Runs';
runsDir = dir( fullfile(BASE_DIR,'Runs') );
runsDir = {runsDir([runsDir.isdir]).name};           %# keep only directory names
runsDir = runsDir( ~ismember(runsDir, {'.' '..'}) ); %# ignore "." and ".."

for r=1:numel(runsDir)
    %# get files in subdirectory
    runFiles = dir(fullfile(BASE_DIR,'Runs',runsDir{r},'*.txt')); %# *.txt files
    runFiles = {runFiles.name};                                   %# file names

    %# map filenames: 1,1.5,2,2.5,... into 1,2,3,4,...
    [~,ord] = sort(str2double( regexprep(runFiles,'\.txt$','') ));
    newrunFiles = cellstr( num2str(ord(:),'Zdata_%d.txt') );
    newrunFiles = strtrim(newrunFiles);

    %# rename files
    for f=1:numel(runFiles)
        fname = fullfile(BASE_DIR,'Runs',runsDir{r},runFiles{f});
        fnameNew = fullfile(BASE_DIR,'Runs',runsDir{r},newrunFiles{f});
        movefile(fname,fnameNew);
    end
end
```

I tested it on the following file structure:

```
Runs/
|
|__Run1/
|  |__1.txt        will become: Zdata_1.txt
|  |__1.5.txt                   Zdata_2.txt
|  |__2.txt                     Zdata_3.txt
|  |__2.5.txt                   etc...
|  |__3.txt
|  |__3.5.txt
|
|__Run2/
   |__1.txt
   |__1.5.txt
   |__2.txt
   |__2.5.txt
   |__3.txt
   |__3.5.txt
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, there are alot of new methods used here, but its great so I can learn them. However when I run the script I get an error (   ??? Error: File: Altrenamefile.m Line: 13 Column:
7)  And I do not really understand what is wrong.
Expression or statement is incorrect--possibly
unbalanced (, {, or [.

Comment: @Abid: I assume it is the call: `[~,ord] = sort(...)`. The [tilde (~) operator](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2009/09/11/matlab-release-2009b-best-new-feature-or/) was introduced in MATLAB R2009b, so if you have older version, replace it with a dummy variable (it means we dont care about that value and wish to ignore it): `[dummy,ord] = sort(...)`

Comment: I think I am having a hard time understanding or setting the paths properly. In the file NumberedQwQoRuns, I have these files : Run1, Run2,....Run9. And Within those files are the .txt files which I wish to rename.  Thank You, Abid

Comment: @Abid: given your description, I would set the variables as: `BASE_DIR = 'c:\MATLAB\Data\';` and use the string `'NumberedQwQoRuns'` instead of `'Runs'` in my code above (mentioned 4 times)

Comment: Thank You so much, this has been bothering me so much! Im absolutely thrilled by how many different ways one simple problem can be fixed in matlab!

Comment: There is one thing which seems to be a result of the coding you developed. For some reason the first few files have two blank spaces before the file name begins, then it decreases to on space after the first 10 files and after the first 100 or so files the remainder of the files have no spacing before the file name. So something like this: "  Zdata_1.txt"..." Zdata_23.txt"..."Zdata100.txt". It seems to change at every orderof magnitude when the numbers get "longer". Is there a certain load command other than load that I can use to get around this?  Best, Abid

Answer (score 0):

Get the actual filename from `subdir(b).name`

Note that you may have problems if your synthesized name matches one of the existing names.